# <form:select capture the code in spring MVC 3.2.8

Tags: html, spring-mvc

I have this class in my Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8.

I have this in my JSP:

```
<script>
    function newWindowLocationAssign(cbCode) {
        alert (cbCode);
    }

</script>

<form:select path="cbCode" id="cbCode" 
items="${cbList}" itemValue="code" 
itemLabel="code" cssStyle="width: 150px"
onchange="javascript:newWindowLocationAssign(this.code);" />
```

But the alert message in null !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<form:select path="cbCode" 
                                                             id="cbCode"
                                                             items="${cbList}" 
                                                             itemValue="code" 
                                                             itemLabel="code"
                                                             cssStyle="width: 150px"
                                                             onchange="javascript:newWindowLocationAssign(this.value);" 
                                                             />
```